# Convert Sql Query to nhibernate query having DateAdd function

Tags: nhibernate, datetime

I have written a SQL query using `DateAdd` function, it need to convert to nhibernate query

```
 select * from Compliance where (PauseDate is not null and BreachDate > PauseDate and
 BreachDate < DateAdd(Hour," +2 +",PauseDate) or (PauseDate is null and BreachDate >  
 GETDATE() and BreachDate < "+jeopardyTime+"))
```

Comment: have you looked into QueryOver<T>?

Comment: what is `" +2 "` and `"+jeopardyTime+"` ?

Answer (score -1):

You can register additional native SQL functions using HQL generators.

See [this blog](http://puredotnetcoder.blogspot.co.at/2012/05/using-dateadd-with-nhibernate-linq.html) illustrating how to use `DATEADD()`